# Understanding foldLeft in Scala

Tags: scala

Please help me understand the below statement.  I couldn't understand how foldLeft works here:

```
scala> l1
res71: List[Double] = List(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

scala> l2
res72: List[Double] = List(1.5, 0.0)

scala> l1.foldLeft(l2) { (a,b) => (b + a.head) :: a}
res73: List[Double] = List(4.5, 3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foldLeft` on `List[A]` looks like this:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B
```

It takes in a seed of type `B`, in your case it's the list `l2`, which usually acts as an accumulator, and a function which receives the accumulator and a value from the list you're folding over, and returns the type of the accumulator.

In your example:

```
(a,b) => (b + a.head) :: a
```

`a` is a `List[Double]`, and b is a value from the `l1` list. It adds the head of the accumulator with the value from `l1` and concatenates it with `a` the accumulator.

I suggest adding a `println` inside the fold function so you can see the values created in each iteration.

Comment: Awesome!  I understood now.  Thank you :)